# ¿Como puedo solucionar este problema con FastAPI?

Tags: fastapi

Estoy trabajando con un dataset de datos (datos de las plataformas: Amazon prime, Disney plus, Hulu, Netflix). Hice unas cuantas transformaciones a estos datos y todo bien hasta ahora.
Lo que sucede es que en el trabajo se solicita lo siguiente (a parte de las transformaciones):

Desarrollo API: Propones disponibilizar los datos de la empresa usando el framework FastAPI, generando diferentes endpoints que se consumiran en la API.

Creas 6 funciones (recuerda que deben tener un decorador por cada una (@app.get(‘/’)):

Película (sólo película, no serie, etc) con mayor duración según año, plataforma y tipo de duración. La función debe llamarse get_max_duration(year, platform, duration_type) y debe devolver sólo el string del nombre de la película.

Cantidad de películas (sólo películas, no series, etc) según plataforma, con un puntaje mayor a XX en determinado año. La función debe llamarse get_score_count(platform, scored, year) y debe devolver un int, con el total de películas que cumplen lo solicitado.

Cantidad de películas (sólo películas, no series, etc) según plataforma. La función debe llamarse get_count_platform(platform) y debe devolver un int, con el número total de películas de esa plataforma. Las plataformas deben llamarse amazon, netflix, hulu, disney.

Actor que más se repite según plataforma y año. La función debe llamarse get_actor(platform, year) y debe devolver sólo el string con el nombre del actor que más se repite según la plataforma y el año dado.

La cantidad de contenidos/productos (todo lo disponible en streaming) que se publicó por país y año. La función debe llamarse prod_per_county(tipo,pais,anio) deberia devolver la cantidada de contenidos/productos segun el tipo de contenido (pelicula,serie) por pais y año en un diccionario con las variables llamadas 'pais' (nombre del pais), 'anio' (año), 'pelicula' (cantidad de contenidos/productos).

La cantidad total de contenidos/productos (todo lo disponible en streaming, series, peliculas, etc) según el rating de audiencia dado (para que publico fue clasificada la pelicula). La función debe llamarse get_contents(rating) y debe devolver el numero total de contenido con ese rating de audiencias.

Deployment: Conoces sobre Render y tienes un tutorial de Render que te hace la vida mas facil  . Tambien podrias usar Railway, pero ten en cuenta que con este si necesitas dockerizacion.

TODO ESO ES LA TAREA QUE HAY PROBLEMAS, me explico:
Ya estan hechos todas las funciones solicitadas y, en teoria, ya esta hecha la API, sin embargo:
Tengo errores del tipo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo nada sobre APIS, por favor si alguien puede ayudarme, dejare tambien LAS FOTOS del archivo main.py:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola SEBASTIAN, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.